# Developing Apps with Panopoly

Tags: panels, features

I'm developing a panopoly App for Services and case studies. I have added my required field and created the content type, added panels and views etc. Finally I created the feature and downloaded for the same. I have done this from the following Documentation. Creating Panopoly Apps. http://drupal.org/node/1704334

I have achieved step 1-4 and I am stuck on step 5 : Integrate the feature with Apps.

Please help to create the feature as an App. I don't have any server setup.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to either create your own apps server using the [Apps Server module](http://drupal.org/project/appserver) or submit your app to an existing app server. In your case, you'll probably want to post on the Panopoly issue queue and ask about the process to do that; @populist will probably be the guy to answer your questions there.

Check out this post for more info on the Drupal apps scene:

http://chocolatelilyweb.ca/blog/drupal-apps-answer-plug-and-play-drupal-site-building